# jquery .change function to populate form fields from database not working with Js dynamically added rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

I have a form that  the user inputs a category into form field categories, other fields on the form like rate, tarriff codes, etc are populated with information from the database, so far i have that working fine, my problem is that the form allows the user to dynamically add rows with those fields in it for another category, but after that row is created when i try to input another category nothing happens the other fields are not being populated like in the first row.

This is the code i am using. This works to get the information for one row but nothing happens for the rest

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() { // This code will be executed when DOM is ready
          $('#categories').change(function() { // When the value for the     
              categories element change, this will be triggered
                 var $self = $(this); // create a jQuery object with the 
                    select inside
                  $.post("getTariffcd.php", { categories : $self.val()}, 
               function(json) {
                if (json && json.status) {
                    $('#tariffcd').val(json.tariff);
                    $('#sub_heading').val(json.subhead);
                    $('#rate').val(json.rate);
                    $('#elevy').val(json.elevy);
                }
             })
          });
        })
    </script>
```

My getTariffcd.php is this

```
    <?php
          $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=customs;charset=utf8", 
              "root", "");

              header("Content-Type:application/json; Charset=utf-8");

                 $st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT tariffcd, sub_heading, rate,  
                       elevy FROM lt_products WHERE categories = 
                         :categories");
                             $st->execute(array ('categories' =>  
                                  $_POST['categories']));
                                     $data = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                         echo json_encode(array ('status' => 
                          true, 'tariff' => $data ['tariffcd'], 'subhead' =>  
                  $data ['sub_heading'], 'rate' => $data ['rate'], 'elevy' 
             => $data ['elevy']));
```

My Form rows are this

```
     <p>        
          <?php //connect to mysql database
               $connection = 
                    mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","customs")or 
                             die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
                               //fetch data from database
                       $sql = "select categories from lt_products";
                     $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error 
          " . mysqli_error($connection));?>

         <input type="text" list="productcategories"   name="categories[]"   
              class="form-control"  id="categories" placeholder="Type Name 
                  of Product" >
                          <datalist id="productcategories">

                              <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, 
                                           MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>
               <option value="<?php echo $row['categories']; ?>"><?php echo 
              $row['categories']; ?></option> <?php } ?>
          </datalist>
    <?php mysqli_close($connection); ?>

     </p>   
        Tariff CD:
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tariffcd[]" 
              disabled="disabled" id="tariffcd">
     </p>
      <p>
        Subheading:
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sub_heading[]" 
              disabled="disabled" id="sub_heading">
      </p>
      <p>
         Rate:
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rate[]" 
             disabled="disabled" id="rate">
      </p>
      <p>
         Environmental:
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="elevy[]" 
              disabled="disabled" id="rate">
      </p>
       <p>
          <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                      <input type="text" name="cost" class="form-control" 
                         id="cost" size="6" maxlength="6" onKeyPress="return  
                           isNumberKey1(event)" placeholder="Cost" <?php if 
                     (isset($_POST['cost'])) echo "value=\"" . 
                  $_POST['cost'] . "\"" ?>>
            <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
        </div>
     </p>
         <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    </button>
               <br>
           <small>Press <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus gs"></span> to 
               add another Item to form :)</small>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

The Java Script to add the rows is this

```
$(function()
 {
   $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();

    var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
        currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
        newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

    newEntry.find('input').val('');
    controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
        .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
        .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
        .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
   }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)
  {
    $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

       e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
 });
```

Any help would be  very much appreciated.